# The difference of closures is a subset of the closure of differences

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that $\overline{A} \setminus \overline{B} \subset \overline{A \setminus B}$
holds for arbitrary sets in a topological space, and I am apparently always going the same wrong ways so is there anybody who could help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Recall that $x \in \overline{A}$ iff every open neighbourhood in some fixed local base at $x$ intersects $A$, and also that given any open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, the collection $$\{ V \subseteq X : V \subseteq U, V\text{ is an open neighbourhood of }x \}$$ is a local base at $x$. (Choose an appropriate open neighbourhood of an arbitrary point $x \in \overline{A} \setminus \overline{B}$ to build a local base as above.)

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: @Lipschitz: Is there some specific part of what I wrote which is troubling you?

Comment: This open neighbourhood construction is completely new to me. My idea was that $\bar{A} \backslash \bar{B} = \bar{A} \cap \bar{B}^C$. The last set is open, so I always get a neighbourhood for $x$ in $\bar{B}^C$. So I can take a local base that is contained in this neighbourhood. Am I moving into the right direction? In that case I would now try to show that there is a non-empty intersection with $A \backslash B$.

Comment: okay, figured it out. thank you!

Comment: @Lipschitz: I did get your ping (or rather my computer did): I didn't realise my local time when I posted my previous comment, and was asleep for much of the interim. (Sorry.) I'm glad you've figured it out, though! (Yes, your idea above seems perfectly fine. Since $x \in \overline{A}$ _every_ open nbhd of $x$ intersects $A$, and if $U \subseteq X \setminus \overline{B}$, we know that $U$ is disjoint from $B$, so any open nbhd of $x$ which is a subset of $X \setminus \overline{B}$ must intersect $A$ at points which are not in $B$, that is, they have nonempty intersection with $A \setminus B$.)